# Nested For Loop To Print Below Mentioned Pattern

Tags: c#

I wanting to print

```
1
23
456
78910
```

in C# Console application, Can any one help in doing it for me
I am using this code which works fine for me but I want not to use if statement just want to show my result in nested loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{  
    Console.Write(i.ToString());

    if (i==1 || i == 3 || i == 6)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: I am not able to come to new line after 1 then 3  then 6, I just able to print numbers from  1 to 10, As I am pretty new to c#

Comment: Show us your current code, not just your problem.

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
           {  


                    Console.Write(i.ToString());


                    if(i==1 || i == 3 || i == 6 )
                    {
               Console.WriteLine();
                 }



               }

Comment: Please spend even a few moments formatting your code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this This should print nummber in format as you mentioned

```
 int len = 0;
            int count = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                count++;
                if (count >= len)
                {
                    len++;
                    count = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                Console.Write(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int len = 1;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 11 ; i++)
{
   count++;
   if(count > len)
   {
      len++;
      count = 0;
      Console.WriteLine("");
   }
   Console.Write(i);
}
```